# Allow a systemd Python service to run shutdown on Linux

Tags: linux, systemd, shutdown

I have a systemd service which runs a Python script that is specified with `ExecStart` in my .service file.  I want the Python script to have permission to shut down the computer while running as a non-privileged user.  I tried adding the following to my .service file:

```
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_SYS_BOOT
```

However, this did not seem to have any effect: the script is still not able to run `/sbin/shutdown`. Is there a way to grant this permission to my script using systemd configuration options?  I'd prefer to avoid `sudo` in my script or adding a command to `/etc/sudoers`.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about hurufu's answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85663/poweroff-or-reboot-as-normal-user ?

Comment: Thanks! That works, but I was hoping to avoid changing `/etc/sudoers`. I verified in `/proc` that my script has CAP_SYS_BOOT permission, which should be inherited by subshells, but I still get a permission error (I'm passing `shell=True` to `subprocess.run`).

Comment: Sorry, not Raphael's answer, hurufu's, the third one, with 2 upvotes.  No sudoers changes. As for your approach - which sounds sensible ... can't comment, never tried that.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I can't make group/user changes due to external constraints, but I like that idea. I think I've solved the problem by writing a helper program in C++, granting it `AmbientCapabilities=CAP_SYS_BOOT`.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica, thank you! Apologies if this question was not quite appropriate for this forum.